# Virtualmin Chroot FTP Users

Tags: debian, chroot

Can someone tell me how to chroot FTP users with Virtualmin, if it is possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this thread?

http://www.virtualmin.com/node/9823

Comment: Virtualmin has an FTP directory restriction option.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is not actually a chroot.  You want the DefaultRoot setting in ProFTPd.

You can set that in Virtualmin by browsing to Webmin>Servers>ProFTPd Server>Files and Directories, and set the option labeled "Limit users to directories" to "Home directory".  Save it, and click "Apply changes" in the upper right corner.